# Not able to make TreePanel work on ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

I was using ExtJS 3.2 and to make the tree panel work I have taken reference from below link and was able to get that done.

https://www.assembla.com/code/yamt/subversion/nodes/trunk/web/js/extjs/examples/ux/XmlTreeLoader.js?rev=9

Now I have to migrate that code in ExtJS 4.1, where I am geeting errors for this code, because Ext.tree.TreeLoader is not working there. So what would be the minimal changes in the same code to make the things work in ExtJS 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.This code is taken from Sencha API.

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: "detention", leaf: true },
            { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                { text: "algebra", leaf: true}
            ] },
            { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

Refer API for more details.